# Explicit form of deformation retraction of $S^{n+1}\setminus\{n,s\}$ onto its equator

Tags: general-topology

Define $A:=\{x\in S^{n+1}: x_{n+1}=0\}$ and call it the equator of $S^{n+1}$, (Obviously, it is homeomorphic to $S^n$.) and let $n,s$ be the north and south poles of $S^{n+1}$.

It is intuitively clear that $A$ is a deformation retract of $S^{n+1}\setminus\{n,s\}$, but I have a trouble finding the explicit form of deformation retraction. What would it be?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the stereographic projection to map $S^n \backslash \{n\}$ homeomorphically into a plane. Removing s corresponds to removing the origin in this plane. Then $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}$ retracts to $S^{n-1}$ via a linear retraction.